# HTTP Request To The Origin Server

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, axios

I'm working on a web application with separate back-end and front-end software.  Both of them are being served from the same server, on different ports (80 and 3000 respectively).

The front-end application (developed in Vue.js) communicates with the back-end server via HTTP requests. I'm using axios library to send those requests.

The problem is, instances of this web application (including both font-end and back-end) is going to be deployed on several different servers for different customers and it seems hard-coding the server address in each of these instances is not the best solution.

How can I configure the axios in the front-end application to send HTTP requests to the same address it is being served from?

For example the instance being served from `example.com` should send the requests to `http://example.com:3000` while the instance being served from `example2.com` should send requests to `http://example2.com:3000`.

Comment: Why not get the current hostname within the frontend app and insert that into any dynamic requests to the backend?

Comment: write a routing rule in your server

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `location.host` property. `Location` is an API for handling manipulations with the url. Its `host` property contains the current host url of the website. For example, if you type in the console `location.host` inside stackoverflow, you'll see *stackoverflow.com*. You can write a mapping for each existing frontend url to map to an API baseUrl, for example:

```
const mapping = {
   'example.com': 'api.example.com',
   'example2.com': 'api.example2.com'
};

function findApiUrl(){
    return mapping[location.host];
}

const baseUrl = findApiUrl(); // pass it to axios
```